# Problem when i do a scatter plot with lot of dates in the x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot, scatter

Im trying to do a scatter plot, when i try to do it, the x axis show a lot of dates. There is a way to put only a few of dates or years in the x axis shown in the scatter plot?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.scatter(terremoto_sur['time'],terremoto_sur['mag'])
plt.title('Magnitud terremotos en el tiempo zona Sur')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Magnitude')
plt.show()
```

[Here is the scatter plot with the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIsNO.png)

Comment: What have you found in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/contents.html)?

Comment: Looks like `terremoto_sur['time']` is strings and not datetimes.

Comment: teremoto_sur['time'] is like this 1906-08-17T00:40:04.000Z, and its a string. Im going to change this huge string list to datatime to see whats happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to tell without seeing the dtype of columns, but what is likely happening is that the 'time' column is not a time-specific pandas datatype like Timestamp or DatetimeIndex. For example, If 'time' is stored with a dtype of `object` then each time data point is essentially a string, and matplotlib simply plots each one with its own tick mark with the string under the tick.

You should check the dtype of your columns, and if necessary, convert the dtype with something like the `to_datetime` method.

Comment: Yeah! I didnt see that my terremoto_sur['time'] its a string type and not a datatime series. When i changed it the scatter plot worked. thx so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set even spacing
`plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MultipleLocator(1))`

You can also try this for sampling every other tick

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::2])
```

Comment: The problem was that my x axis was not a datatime so i changed it and with your code my plot looks amazing. Thank you so much <3